# segfault because of missing header files

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

I had forgotten to put a 3rd party "header only" library header (.h) files into the correct path when building a shared object. It built fine - retrospectively surprising.

When run a segfault occurred exactly at the line when that 3rd party lib was used in my shared object.

The part I do not understand is when I copied those header files to the path specified with `#include`, I could not cause a segfault. I did not even re-build the object. The very strange thing is that when I mv the dir the header files are in, it still worked - no segfault. However, when I completely rm the dir, it crashed. Does it look for header files the current dir and subdirs? I've also got that header-only library in the standard(?) `/usr/local/include`

I've not worked with shared objects before. I usually create static objects and include them in the build. The flags I used to create the shared object in question are `-shared -fPIC`

I'd like to understand this behavior. It's interesting because of deployment. Do I need to include those header files when deploying on the production machine? Essentially I don't want to have that as a dependency as it is a "header-only" lib.

**edit**

Code:

```
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>

void MyClass::myFunction()
{
    rapidjson::StringBuffer string;
    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> jsonWriter(string);
}
```

Here is a link to the debug session:
http://pastebin.com/a0FaQwf1

Comment: It could be because when you didn't include the header, the automatically generated function prototype might missmatch the actual function, so the compiler does something stupid which causes the segfault.

Comment: Also, you have been a member for so long that you should know we need to see some code to really be able to help you.

Comment: How many times have you tested this correlation? It could just be undefined behavior in your program, manifesting itself as segfault at random times.

Comment: No compiler warnings. I've tested this 3 times to make sure of what I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You never need to supply header files to the user in order to run the program.

Your library probably just refines defaults,
that is the reason why it do not fail when missing at compile time

Answer (score 0):

An explanation for the strange move/remove behavior could be that the shared object was still loaded into memory during the move and kept an open file handle to something in the include dir.

You know, under ext2/3/4 open files are connected to inodes and not to dir paths. Thus moving an open file won't harm. On the other hand IIRC also removing won't harm. The freeing of the inode will be delayed until all processes have closed the file. Maybe this just happened between your mv and rm.

Comment: Can you point to documentation for this? Also, your comment about moving "won't harm" is only true if the move is within the same file system...

Comment: Sorry, I have no docs at hand and would need to search by myself. You're right that this is only true within a single file system.